# Quadrants passed through by a line

Tags: code-golf, number, geometry

### Task

Given a representation of a line, output the number of [quadrants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)) that that line passes through.

### Valid Representations of a Line

You can represent a line as

- Three signed integers `A`, `B`, and `C` which share no common factor and where `A` and `B` are not both zero, representing the line `Ax + By = C`,
- Four signed integers `X1`, `Y1`, `X2`, and `Y2`, representing the line passing through the points `(X1, Y1)` and `(X2, Y2)`, or
- A data type that describes a line, if your language has one (it must support vertical lines).

You may *not* take input in any format that does not allow for a vertical line (e.g. slope-intercept form). If you choose to take integers as input, you can assume that they lie in the inclusive range `[-127, 128]`.

### Specifications

- The output will always be 0, 2, or 3 (a line can never pass through all four quadrants, nor can it pass through only a single one).
- A line on an axis is considered not to pass through any quadrants. A line through the origin is considered to only pass through 2 quadrants.
- You do not have to return which quadrants are being passed through (though the test cases include them for clarity).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer (measured in bytes) wins.

### Test Cases

You will have to convert these to a suitable format before using them.

```
1x + 1y = 1   ->  3  (quadrants I, II, and IV)
-2x + 3y = 1  ->  3  (quadrants I, II, and III)
2x + -3y = 0  ->  2  (quadrants III and I)
1x + 1y = 0   ->  2  (quadrants II and IV)
3x + 0y = 6   ->  2  (quadrants I and IV)
-3x + 0y = 5  ->  2  (quadrants II and III)
0x + -8y = 4  ->  2  (quadrants III and IV)
0x + 1y = 0   ->  0  (lies on the x-axis)
1x + 0y = 0   ->  0  (lies on the y-axis)
```

Comment: They should teach the tactic we all borrowed from Leaky Nun in school, if there was a need for it.

Answer (score 22):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda a:3<<a.count(0)&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRytjGJlEvOb80r0TDQFPN@H9BUSaQmaYRbagDhLGamlxwEV0jHWM0ISMdXWMdAxQhkD5UEaAKHTNUk0BCpihCBjq6FjomaELoJsFE/gMA)

Comment: ... wow. This is more trivial than I thought.

Comment: You could maybe use a string instead of a list if the I/O permits it.

Comment: Would using `'320'[a.count(0)]` and returning the value in string form be acceptable?

Comment: And wow, looks like all answers will now be "based off Leaky's"

Comment: @FlipTack bithacks win :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
TL’ȧ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/E51HDzBPLVf4fbn/UtCby//9oQx0gjNVRiNY10jGGsIx0dI11DEAskCSYAeTrmIFVgVimIJaBjq6FjgmEBVUFYQAA)

- -1 byte thanks to Challenger5
- -1 byte thanks to Leaky Nun
- -2 bytes thanks to H.PWiz

No longer based off Leaky's answer!

Comment: `ċ0ị2,0,3` saves a byte

Comment: @Challenger5 Huh, so it does. Thanks!

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9It4Hx4WWHVqua/P//P9pQBwhjAQ)

Comment: How about `TL’ȧ$`. Don't know Jelly, so this might be golfable

Comment: @H.PWiz Very nice! I don't think that can be golfed, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Wait, so this computes `(number of non-zeroes) && (number of non-zeroes - 1)`? I don't get `$` here to be honest...

Comment: @totallyhuman IIUC `$` makes the previous two links into a single monadic chain so that the chain does not start with 3 dyads (as Jelly has special behavior for this).

Comment: ...yep `$` treats the last two links as if they were a monadic (`TLµ’ȧ` will do too, as would `TL_Ị$` or `TLµ_Ị`) - although it does not create an actual chain.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>30</s> <s>24</s> 22 bytes

This is my first time trying to golf in Javascript.  <s>There's gotta be a better way to count zeros...</s>

```
(a,b,c)=>3<<!a+!b+!c&3
```

-6 bytes thanks to Herman Lauenstein, -2 bytes to remembering operator precedences.

Alternate 24-bytes solution to return a string instead:

```
(a,b,c)=>"320"[!a+!b+!c]
```

Comment: That's actually fairly clever...

Comment: 24 bytes by not using an array `(a,b,c)=>3<<(!a+!b+!c)&3`

Comment: Looks like I can't golf mine to not use an array anymore...

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ƵÜ¹0¢è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//2NbDcw7tNDi06PCK//@jDXQUdC10FExiAQ)

Based on Leaky Nun's answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
0233{.‽X
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MDIzMyU3Qi4ldTIwM0RY,inputs=MyUwQTAlMEE2)

Based off Leaky Nun's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148601/59183).

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 13 bytes

```
M`\b0
T`d`320
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w3zchJsmAKyQhJcHYyOD/f0MdIOQy0jGGkgZcIBEDLiBLxwxMmnIZ6FjomABJkDiYBAA)

Also based on Leaky Nun's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148601/34718).

Comment: This doesn't work if the input contains `10` for example. The first regex would need to be `\b0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
~{!!}%{+}*.1>*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v65aUbFWtVq7VkvP0E7r//9oEwUjBYNYAA)

- @Challenger5 -2 bytes

This program takes an array of 3 integers representing the coefficients in the equation `Ax + By = C`

**Example Input/Output**

```
[1 1 1]   -> 3
[-2 3 1]  -> 3
```

**How it Works**

```
~                       - Eval string (input)
  {  }%                 - Map to array
   !!                   - Double not (equivalent to != 0)
        {+}*            - total array (fold addition)
            .           - Duplicate top of stack
             1>         - Greater than 1?
               *        - Multiply
```

This was a little tricky at first for me to figure out a mathematical way to calculate this. However there are only 8 possible configurations such that `a != 0 & b != 0 & c != 0`

```
0 0 0 = 0
a 0 0 = 0
0 b 0 = 0
0 0 c = 0
a 0 c = 2
0 b c = 2
a b 0 = 2
a b c = 3
```

I eventually came to the following function.

```
F(a,b,c) {
    var r = sign(a)+sign(b)+sign(c);
    if(r > 1)
        r;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

and the whole thing can be condensed to a single math problem

```
F(a,b,c) {
    return (sign(a)+sign(b)+sign(c)) * (sign(a)+sign(b)+sign(c) > 1);
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `{!!}%` instead of `[{!!}/]`.

Comment: CJam translation of this submission is `{:!:!:+_1>*}`.

Comment: @Challenger5 lol, How did I not realize that. Also nice port, I just have to learn how to read it now.

Comment: Significant differences in this case are 1) shorthand for mapping (`:!` is equivalent to `{!}%`), 2) shorthand for reducing (`:+` is equivalent to `{+}*`), 3) that `.` is changed to `_` (because CJam has floats), and 4) that CJam does not have input on the stack by default, meaning that you wrap the code in `{}` to make it a function.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```apl
0⌈3-×⍨+/0=⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@Gzzq6TDWPTz9Ue8KbX0DW6Dsf6D4fwUwSOMyVDBUMAAA)

`⎕IO` is `0`. Thanks to @Adám for -3 bytes!

Comment: [`0⌈3-×⍨+/0=⎕`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@Gzzq6TDWPTz9Ue8KbX0DW6Dsf6D4fwUwSOMyVDBUMAAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 25 bytes

```
_=>3<<!_[0]+!_[1]+!_[2]&3
```

Based off Leaky Nun's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 22 bytes

```hs
f l="320"!!sum[1|0<-l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hx1bJ2MhASVGxuDQ32rDGwEY3J/Z/bmJmnoKtQm5iga@CRkFpSXBJkU@egp6ChpWCkpImkJGmyaUABNEK0YY6CiAUC@brKETrGukoGCMLAPm6QAEDuABEB4IPktRRMEOYABEwhQsAOboWOgomyAKGaCYagPgKsf8B)

### Point-free solution, 27 bytes

```hs
("320"!!).(\l->sum[1|0<-l])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBDoIwEEX3nuLTVZu0pIAaY8QT6MplYdEQUWNLGoGdZ7cWSYA4@Yt5bzL/rtvn1Rhf54WnJEsliSIW08KIY9tblbzlQZiSeasfDXJY7c6gru8u3evUIAbdgxAWlpqtEEZBJRxDyh9zKJFyZEsRWAQhJzF@zDwcObZzwyg2kwggdhzrpUj@GuXAKP2nqo2@tV5Uzn0B)

Comment: I was about to suggest that change... beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 18 bytes

```
{3+<@_.grep(0)+&3}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ABCR](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/ABCR), 30 bytes

Input is in the form `A,B,C` where the commas can be replaced by any non-numeric, non-`-` character.

```
BBi7baxci7baxci7bax@7)A7(xxo
```

No online interpreter yet, but here's an explanation:

```
BB                                Add two values to the B queue. (Values are unimportant)
  i7 ax                           Read in a number.  If it's non-zero...
    b                             Dequeue one item from the B queue.
       c                          Read in the delimiter...
        i                         ... And promptly overwrite it with the next number.
         7baxci7bax               Repeat the whole "if 0, dequeue from B" for the
                                     other two input numbers.
                   @              Get the current length of the B queue. [2, 1, or 0]
                    7             If the length isn't 0...
                     )            ... Increment it to our required [3,2,0]
                      A           ... And enqueue it to A.
                                  (We don't need to add to A otherwise, because it defaults
                                    to 0 already if there's no value in it.
                                    I used that to exit the queue with 7_ax earlier.)
                       7(xx       Set the register to 0 to exit from loop.
                           o      Peek A and print as a number.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Deorst), 12 bytes

```
l0EN))A:k?Z+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f8/x8DVT1PT0SrbPkr7//9oQx0gjAUA)

Somewhat based off [Leaky's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148601/66833); uses the same premise, but a different mapping method.

### How it works

Deorst has a count occurrences builtin, but doesn't (for some reason) have an indexing command, so I had to create the following mapping, where the left is `a.count(0)` and the right is the wanted result

```
0 -> 3
1 -> 2
2 -> 0
```

The program itself works like this (example input of `[1,1,1]`)

```
l0           - Push 0;     STACK = [[1 1 1] 0]
  EN         - Count;      STACK = [0]
    ))       - Subtract 2; STACK = [-2]
      A      - Absolute;   STACK = [2]
       :     - Duplicate;  STACK = [2 2]
        k?Z  - Positive?;  STACK = [2 1]
           + - Sum;        STACK = [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 23 bytes

```
D,f,@@@,!$!@!s2$_|d0$>+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HwcFBR1FF0UGx2EglvibFQMVO@////wZAaAwA)

Based off both [my Deorst answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148607/66833) and [Leaky's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148601/66833)

### How it works

```
D,f,@@@,  - Create a triadic function. 
            Example arguments;   [1 1 1]
        ! - Logical NOT; STACK = [1 1 0]
        $ - Swap;        STACK = [1 0 1]
        ! - Logical NOT; STACK = [1 0 0]
        @ - Reverse;     STACK = [0 0 1]
        ! - Logical NOT; STACK = [0 0 0]
        s - Sum;         STACK = [0]
        2 - Push 2;      STACK = [0 2]
        $ - Swap;        STACK = [2 0]
        _ - Subtract;    STACK = [-2]
        | - Absolute;    STACK = [2]
        d - Duplicate;   STACK = [2 2]
        0 - Push 0;      STACK = [2 2 0]
        $ - Swap;        STACK = [2 0 2]
        > - Greater to;  STACK = [2 1]
        + - Sum;         STACK = [3]
```

However, I think I've been using functions too much in Add++, rather than the main code body. So I attempted to do this using both functions, and the code body, and resulted in a much nicer 50 byte piece (yes, that is the longest answer here):

```python
# Example input: 1 1 1;
# x and y are the accumulators

D,f,@@@,!$!@!s # Count the 0s
$f>?>?>?       # Call f with the input.
-2   # Subtract 2;    x: -2;  y: 0
^2   # Square;        x: 4;   y: 0
S    # Square root;   x: 2.0; y: 0
\1   # To integer;    x: 2;   y: 0
y:x  # Assign x to y; x: 2;   y: 2
}    # Switch to y;   x: 2;   y: 2
>0   # Is positive?;  x: 2;   y: 1
}    # Switch to x;   x: 2;   y: 1
+y   # Add y to x;    x: 3;   y: 1
O    # Print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HwcFBR1FF0UGxmEslzc4eBLl0jbjijLiCuWIMuSqtKrhquewMgIR2JZf/////DUEQAA)